# Maven scm git tag behaving strangely

Tags: git, maven, maven-scm

I am not a Maven expert and so this might be obvious, but it defies everything that I've seen and read.

I am using the git scm provider to create a tag. I can get it to work correctly, but I have to supply the tag on the command line and put the scm info in the parent POM.

If I don't move the scm info to the parent it complains that the connectionUrl is not defined. Works fine in parent POM (not a big deal I guess).

Next is more of a pain with the tag

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.9.4:tag (default-cli) on project mavenIRIS: The parameters 'tag' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.9.4:tag are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]`

And here is my POM info:

```
    <profile>
        <id>updateTag</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>build.mode</name>
                <value>release</value>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <git>jgit</git>
                        <tag>testTag</tag>
                        <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jgit</artifactId>
                            <version>1.9.4</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>                     
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>tag</goal>
                        </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Thanks

Comment: I am experimenting the same issue did you find a way around ?

Answer (score 0):

i also faced the same issue. i added the following profile and invoked. it worked well

`<profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.scm.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                            <providerImplementations>
                                <git>jgit</git>
                            </providerImplementations>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jgit</artifactId>
                                <version>${maven.scm.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the following SCM information in your POM:

```
<scm>
 <connection>scm:git:ssh:<your url></connection>
 <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh:<your url></developerConnection>
 <url>scm:git:ssh:<your url></url>
</scm>
```